# What does /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot do?

Tags: c++, rpm

I am building a RPM package for a c++ application. The compilation and installation succeed. Then the the following command fails `/usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot` with the following error:

```
Found '/user/dfsdf/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vendor-xerces-c-3.1.3-3.1.3-1.x86_64' in installed files; aborting
```

I haven't found any documentation about this command. What does check-buildroot does?

Comment: The command is not called in the same way. The result list you send me is showing the documentation for buildrpm, not check-buildroot.

Comment: Gone now, though you could have improved your question with a bit more evidence of your research so far.

Comment: Thanks.. True! I'll do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a [pointer](http://rpm5.org/community/rpm-devel/att-0747/check-buildroot) to a copy of the script.  Because it is considered an "internal" part of `rpmbuild` (in `/usr/lib/rpm`, rather than `/usr/bin`), there is no manual page for it.

However, it is known to people who troubleshoot problems building rpms.

The script checks for a common problem: when building an rpm, your package compiles and installs into a `BUILDROOT` directory.  If it is done properly, no trace of that directory name will remain in the final package.  Occurrences of the *actual* installation directory, e.g., `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, etc., are okay.

Further reading:

- [rpmdevtools-5.3-1.el4 RPM for noarch](ftp://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/4/ppc/rpmdevtools-5.3-1.el4.noarch.html) describes the rpmdevtools and gives its changelog.
- [pk's Tech Page](http://pktechpage.blogspot.com/2015/09/found-rpmbuildroot-in-installed-files.html) discusses a change that a developer made based on the `check-buildroot` message.
- [check-buildroot failure](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-devel-list/2007-July/msg01700.html) is another example where it was used
- [How do I safely remove a path string from a compiled library without corrupting the library?](https://serverfault.com/questions/713205/how-do-i-safely-remove-a-path-string-from-a-compiled-library-without-corrupting) illustrates the real problem: getting good advice.

Comment: I solved my issue. Thank you very much for your help. The third link was extremely useful.

Comment: @GiuseppePes how you fix your issue? Thomas didn't mention any solution.